# How do I push items to array with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Push items on to "entrants" array not working. Anybody know why?

```
<script>
function taz() {

  var entrants = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 48; i++) {
    entrants.push('#P' + i);
  }

  return entrants; 
  alert(entrants.length); 
  console.log(taz());
}

</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen `#` used like that before, what are you trying to do with it? Are you attempting to iterate a variable name perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I have 48 variables named id="P1" id="P2" etc.

Comment: Can you just store these values in an array to begin with rather than naming a bunch of variables? For example an array named `P`, then access with `P[0], P[1], etc..`

Comment: not really. They are in a <form>.

Comment: How are you getting the values out of the form? Most libraries will put them in an object not a bunch of variables.

Comment: They are on the webpage.

Comment: I think you should think about how you are extracting the data, are you able to provide an example of the html form structure?

Comment: I understand that, but at some point they are accessed and stored in variables in javascript. Your *real* problem is all those variables — that makes everything very inconvenient and messy.

Comment: Sure. <input id="P1" /> <input id="P2" /> etc.

Comment: looks like you are trying to alert / console.log after a `return`. anything after `return` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need the keys to be named, you're looking for an object rather than an array.

```js
function taz() {

  var entrants = {};
  for (var i = 1; i <= 48; i++) {
   entrants['P' + i] = 'Some Value' + i;
  }
 
  return entrants;
}

console.log(taz());
```

However, it might make more sense to store the data in an array, in which case you wouldn't have named keys.

```js
function taz() {

  var entrants = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 48; i++) {
   entrants.push('Some Value' + i);
  }
 
  return entrants;
}

console.log(taz());
```

Comment: This answers the question well but I think it's worth addressing the loop condition `i <= 48`, and why having a fixed number there is probably unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I copied the code to the question. But it doesn't work. Can you tell me why?